# Position labels in automatic way at end of a line

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using tkiz, I would like to position labels at line ends in automatic way.

Unfortunately "auto" centers labels at ends of line.

Example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\ua[6]{%
    \draw (#1) -- (#4)
        node[at start, auto=left]{#2}
        node[at start, auto=right]{#3}
        node[at end, auto=left]{#5}
        node[at end, auto=right]{#6};
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm]

    \node(a)[draw, rectangle, align=left]{A\\head};
    \node(b)[draw, rectangle, right=of a, align=left]{B\\head};
    \node(c)[draw, rectangle, below=of b, align=left]{C\\head};
    \node(d)[draw, rectangle, left=of c, align=left]{D\\head};

    \ua{a}{a1 label}{a2 label}{b}{b1 label}{b2 label}
    \ua{b}{b3 label}{b4 label}{c}{c1 label}{c2 label}
    \ua{c}{c3 label}{c4 label}{d}{d1 label}{d2 label}
    \ua{d}{d3 label}{d4 label}{a}{a3 label}{a4 label}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would expect something like this (and you can see why I am trying to have a command for a line with labels here)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node=./style={align=center}, node distance=4cm]

    \node(a)[draw, rectangle, align=left]{A\\head};
    \node(b)[draw, rectangle, right=of a, align=left]{B\\head};
    \node(c)[draw, rectangle, below=of b, align=left]{C\\head};

    \draw (a) -- (b)
        node[at start, anchor=south west]{a1 label}
        node[at start, anchor=north west]{a2 label}
        node[at end, anchor=south east]{b1 label}
        node[at end, anchor=north east]{b2 label};

    \draw (b) -- (c)
        node[at start, anchor=north east]{b1 label}
        node[at start, anchor=north west]{b2 label}
        node[at end, anchor=south east]{c1 label}
        node[at end, anchor=south west]{c2 label};

    % ... and so on...
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note: I know about "pos", "near end", "near start" and so on, but with short labels you get not very nice result and with long labels you still will overlap with the main nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method using `let`, `calc` and `label` :

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=50]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\ua[6]{
    \draw (#1) -- (#4) 
        let 
            \p1=($(#4)-(#1)$), 
            \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} % for PGF < 3.0 atan2(\x1,\y1) 
        in
        node[at start, label={\n1+45:#2}]{}
        node[at start, label={\n1-45:#3}]{}
        node[at end, label={\n1+135:#5}]{}
        node[at end, label={\n1+225:#6}]{};
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm, label distance=-2mm]

    \node(a)[draw, rectangle, align=left]{A\\head};
    \node(b)[draw, rectangle, right=of a, align=left]{B\\head};
    \node(c)[draw, rectangle, below=of b, align=left]{C\\head};
    \node(d)[draw, rectangle, left=of c, align=left]{D\\head};

    \ua{a}{a1 label}{a2 label}{b}{b1 label}{b2 label}
    \ua{b}{b3 label}{b4 label}{c}{c1 label}{c2 label}
    \ua{c}{c3 label}{c4 label}{d}{d1 label}{d2 label}
    \ua{d}{d3 label}{d4 label}{a}{a3 label}{a4 label}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** After the comment of wrobell I have replaced `\n1={90-scalar(atan2(\p1))}` with `\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)}` to make the code more readable.

Comment: I am getting error `! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function 'scalar' (in '90-scalar(atan2(141.43
257pt,0.0pt))')`. Tried with lualatex.

Comment: @wrobell Did you have PGF 3.0 ? If not, for PGF 2.1 you should put something like `\n1={atan2(\p1)}`. And even for 3.0 `scalar` is optional here. In 3.0 `atan2` is different from `atan2` in 2.x (only x and y are interchanged).

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion. If your second example is good for you, write a command which implements it. You'll need two commands, one for horizontal lines and another for vertical ones. All horizontal paths will go from left to right and verticals from top to bottom. You'll have to correct anchors from next code, but it can help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\horzpath[6]{%
    \draw (#1) -- (#4)
        node[at start, anchor=south west]{#2}
        node[at start, anchor=north west]{#3}
        node[at end, anchor=south east]{#5}
        node[at end, anchor=north east]{#6};
}

\newcommand\vertpath[6]{%
    \draw (#1) -- (#4)
        node[at start, anchor=north west]{#2}
        node[at start, anchor=north east]{#3}
        node[at end, anchor=south east]{#5}
        node[at end, anchor=south west]{#6};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm]

    \node(a)[draw, rectangle, align=left]{A\\head};
    \node(b)[draw, rectangle, right=of a, align=left]{B\\head};
    \node(c)[draw, rectangle, below=of b, align=left]{C\\head};
    \node(d)[draw, rectangle, left=of c, align=left]{D\\head};

    \horzpath{a}{a1 label}{a2 label}{b}{b1 label}{b2 label}
    \vertpath{b}{b3 label}{b4 label}{c}{c1 label}{c2 label}
    \horzpath{d}{d1 label}{d2 label}{c}{c3 label}{c4 label}
    \vertpath{a}{a3 label}{a4 label}{d}{d3 label}{d4 label}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it is not "automatic" enough. Beside vert/horiz modes you need to run the lines from top to down and from left to right or positioning will not work.